# Discord.JS | Auto-Kick someone after posting a specific link?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Im trying to add some "auto-mod" features to my bot, recently I added a small command that will delete fake steam trade links (as they seem to be getting more common every day) [as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68lmF.png) basically it token logs your discord account, then spams the same message in all of your servers. So I developed some code to auto-delete these links, and reply with a gif... but I want more, as I believe these bots don't stop spamming until they are removed from the server, so I want to add a function to auto kick them, and DM them a message about why they were kicked, and an invite back to the server (as most of these people quickly get their accounts back) sorry for the long talk, my current WORKING code is below:

```
client.on('message', (message) => { //whenever a message is sent
if (message.content.includes('https://stearncomminuty.ru/tradofferr/new/?partner=1284276379&token=iMNdOshG')) { 
  message.delete() //delete the message
    .then(message.channel.send('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/859211601726275636/859977676919013386/5f36hh.gif'))
}})
```

Any help or suggested improvements would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are unfortunately not a code-writing service.  You have lots of basic questions which are best left to the documentation or Google where they are already highly-covered topics in great depth.  A good place to start is looking up "how to kick member discord js", "how to send user dm discord js", and "how to send invite discord js" for each of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this really simply. Just add another `.then()` after your first one and call the [`<guildMember>.kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick) function.

For example:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => { //whenever a message is sent
    if (message.content.includes('https://stearncomminuty.ru/tradofferr/new/?partner=1284276379&token=iMNdOshG')) {
        message.delete() //delete the message
            .then(message.channel.send('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/859211601726275636/859977676919013386/5f36hh.gif'))
            .then(() => message.member.kick('User kicked for sending spam links.'))
    }
});
```

---

Also, why don't you just put `https://stearncomminuty.ru/tradofferr/` in your `include()`? This will also delete similar fake-steam-URLs and not just a specific one because it is not unlikely that there are lots of URLs starting like this.

Comment: I tried something like this, but could not get it to work, I probably just messed it up, and thanks! I had | .then(user.kick) | and will "User kicked for sending spam links" be DM's to them? or show only in audit logs.

Comment: It will be in audit logs. You can use `<GuildMember>.send('message')` after the kick if you want to send it to the kicked user (with another `.then()`)